# How to add parameter in the addTarget's selector?

Tags: objective-c, button, selector

Say I have a function like this:

```
-(void)activateDict:(NSNumber*)dictID{
```

}

Then I add a action for my button:

```
 [aBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(activateDict) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

There is a parameter in the activateDict function, which is (NSNumber*)dictID,
so when I add the action to button, how can I add the parameter to the function?
like: action:@selector(activateDict:theDictID).

Answer (score 0):

You would normally define activateDict as `activateDict: (id) sender` and then make dictID an ivar of sender.

Comment: if possible can you explain with some code snippet.How to make dictId an iVar of sender?